# How to append a PDF file to a LaTeX and keep its aspect ratio?

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

I would like to append a PDF file to a LaTeX document and keep its aspect ratio, which is different than the original aspect ratio of the document.

To clarify, I have a PDF file which is a standard PDF export of a PowerPoint presentation, so it has 16x9 aspect ratio, and I would like to append this to a document which is a default A4 paper. So, I want a single PDF file compiled which has separate aspect ratio and sizes for different sections. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `pdfpages` package and include the pdf with the `fitpaper=true` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

test

\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{example-image-16x9}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: @kolmogorov You're welcome!